# C++ How do I return an object containing a pointer without triggering the destructor?

Tags: c++

code looks like this

```
#include<iostream>
class A
{
public:
    int* a;
    char name;
    A(char _n = 'N')
    {
        a = 0;
        name = _n;
    }
    A(int _a, int _b, char _n = 'N')
    {
        name = _n;
        a = new int[2]{ _a, _b };
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "deleting object..." << name << "\n";
        delete[] a;
    }
    //
    void operator=(A b)
    {
        std::cout << "cleanup begin\n";
        delete[] a;
        a = new int[] {b.a[0], b.a[1]};
    }
    //
    A Copy()
    {
        if (a == 0) return *new A();
        A* _r = new A(a[0], a[1], name + 1);
        return *_r;
    }
};

//

int main()
{
    A d{0, 1, 'T'};
    {
        A Z(0, 1);
        Z = Z.Copy();
    }
    std::cout << "check\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I want Z = Z.Copy() to work but instead it triggers a breakpoint in delete_scalar.
From what i understand, the overloaded = should free the memory that is allocated to member a, after which it should allocate new memory and copy the integers by value, then destroying b.
Even so, object Z from the nameless scope has its destructor called twice, leading to the breakpoint trigger.

All that I want is to be able to do something like this:

```
x = (x - y) * z + y;
```

where I can overload = for x to assign to it the result of overloaded object operations (x and y are custom vector3 instances, z is a custom Matrix4 instance, Matrix4 contains a float*, if that's relevant).
So, what is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: You need to follow [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I heartily recommend the rule of zero, which means you don't create and handle your own pointers. If you need a dynamic array of values, use `std::vector`.

Comment: The shown code does not match your description. There is no "b=b.Copy()" in the shown code. There is no "delete_scalar" in the shown code. Although your question seems straightforward to answer, past experience suggests that attempts to answer questions with fake or inaccurate code often end up being very unproductive. Can you [edit] your question so that it's internally consistent with itself.

Comment: Also note that your copy-assignment operator is flawed: By taking its argument by value it does an extra copy which isn't handle properly (since you don't have a copy-constructor). The copy-assignment operator should look like `A& operator=(A const&);`

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [this operator overloading canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will the copy constructor get called when passing an instance of A to some function as an argument ?

Comment: If it's passed by value, it will. Because that's what passing by value means: a copy gets created. Therefore, according to fundamental rules of C++ a copy constructor gets invoked.

Comment: Your A::Copy() will end up generating momory leaks.

Comment: `Copy` will leak because it uses e.g. `return *new A`. That will dynamically allocate a new `A` object, the return the object but not the pointer. The pointer is lost, and can't be passed to `delete` anywhere. All `new` must be match with a `delete`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i thought that i would get the object's reference like that so the memory would get freed after leaving scope, but it seems i was wrong, thank you for the tip on copy constructors, after refactoring a bit they fixed the problem (i thought the = overload would do the same thing but oh well) <3